# Sync done but latest block number 0

Tags: go-ethereum

I am running geth 1.8.0
I have been running the node for over 24 hours

```
> eth.syncing
false
> eth.getBlock("latest").number
0
```

Is this a valid state?

Why is the number 0 even though syncing is complete

Peers

```
> admin.peers
[{
    caps: ["eth/62", "eth/63", "les/1", "les/2"],
    id: "1118980bf48b0a3640bdba04e0fe78b1add18e1cd99bf22d53daac1fd9972ad650df52176e7c7d89d1114cfef2bc23a2959aa54998a46afcf7d91809f0855082",
    name: "Geth/v1.7.3-stable/linux-amd64/go1.7",
    network: {
      inbound: false,
      localAddress: "172.31.22.171:51030",
      remoteAddress: "52.74.57.123:30303",
      static: false,
      trusted: false
    },
    protocols: {
      eth: {
        difficulty: 2.562703311832198e+21,
        head: "0x447386c92b3d4658cc7764d82aaec83d6c4a7a18f6fe87dd558396327964ee39",
        version: 63
      }
    }
}, {
    caps: ["eth/62", "eth/63", "les/1", "les/2"],
    id: "138ec659b5ec02029c0c08d4a8f377174622c4d4f8684cf22bd6393a1e46e731ed1bf87249f4003f4c47f7a39611c39e0dc7004091604183d6e5781f1eaf81be",
    name: "Geth/v1.8.0-stable-5f540757/linux-amd64/go1.9.4",
    network: {
      inbound: false,
      localAddress: "172.31.22.171:45178",
      remoteAddress: "79.98.29.93:30303",
      static: false,
      trusted: false
    },
    protocols: {
      eth: {
        difficulty: 2.562703311832198e+21,
        head: "0x447386c92b3d4658cc7764d82aaec83d6c4a7a18f6fe87dd558396327964ee39",
        version: 63
      }
    }
}, {
    caps: ["eth/62", "eth/63"],
    id: "1bbae192d212e6d91748e72dfa0eb2f97b9dadcb7fdcb7f535dcde652ee91856e5db3f9a71b4a7a9252650acb8e150b7b401a600d131c108fa283bd017628370",
    name: "Geth/v1.7.3-stable-4bb3c89d/linux-amd64/go1.9.2",
    network: {
      inbound: false,
      localAddress: "172.31.22.171:54778",
      remoteAddress: "173.212.235.16:30303",
      static: false,
      trusted: false
    },
    protocols: {
      eth: {
        difficulty: 2.269417677247923e+21,
        head: "0xaf4818557d616ad6ed896aa8abf3be2c83a7e175c07ea7ae434d27ded196c959",
        version: 63
      }
    }
}, {
    caps: ["eth/62", "eth/63"],
    id: "209a2c2862760b2d63da23780507b373de397b39589ddf50a6bf11f828268d604b0ecfd06390d7f9d72c516d77b364ea573fe12d7c29d18342f0a6fa4ca3c260",
    name: "Geth/v1.7.2-stable-1db4ecdc/windows-amd64/go1.9",
    network: {
      inbound: false,
      localAddress: "172.31.22.171:42810",
      remoteAddress: "184.12.106.238:30303",
      static: false,
      trusted: false
    },
    protocols: {
      eth: {
        difficulty: 2.554069593289375e+21,
        head: "0x8856b4ede4ccfc4be4ed723b306ae8874b444a2a0aa44e86201192500ddafb90",
        version: 63
      }
    }
}, {
    caps: ["eth/62", "eth/63"],
    id: "318ed633acf08141bd9badc4b9c7983e58b64e06d9b957f8e80b385cbefe8b211594dec2e0a40b3f94ebeeb41383b22704841a4a99e9ffb0b7ad930fd2beecd7",
    name: "Geth/pubnode/v1.7.3-stable-4bb3c89d/linux-amd64/go1.9.2",
    network: {
      inbound: false,
      localAddress: "172.31.22.171:43452",
      remoteAddress: "52.192.57.242:30303",
      static: false,
      trusted: false
    },
    protocols: {
      eth: {
        difficulty: 2.5626594943418226e+21,
        head: "0x37ad0388509b48f6028c782a0f619b951de1ee50bcaaac5597a2062e48ab0e58",
        version: 63
      }
    }
}, {
    caps: ["eth/63"],
    id: "648aa55343ca96ff026c18990bfde40a80ab61090d99bb28f0ae60299cfa0c9478538e38919fb57e3ddf2e7ec3df2b778a15fcd2a4582ebdae020e1bf5ad6d78",
    name: "Geth/v1.7.3-stable-4bb3c89d/linux-amd64/go1.9",
    network: {
      inbound: false,
      localAddress: "172.31.22.171:56590",
      remoteAddress: "86.148.23.224:30303",
      static: false,
      trusted: false
    },
    protocols: {
      eth: {
        difficulty: 17179869184,
        head: "0xd4e56740f876aef8c010b86a40d5f56745a118d0906a34e69aec8c0db1cb8fa3",
        version: 63
      }
    }
}, {
    caps: ["eth/62", "eth/63"],
    id: "7e3c72d20c40b6606f07e9cf726a223cf28c2a71e83354f72187fe64dc857791cde27210aac1074c818fe216d46f2e0933a392a2d3c035ed173b3467b1e3e6fb",
    name: "Geth/v1.7.3-stable/linux-amd64/go1.8.5",
    network: {
      inbound: false,
      localAddress: "172.31.22.171:39010",
      remoteAddress: "13.115.174.21:30303",
      static: false,
      trusted: false
    },
    protocols: {
      eth: {
        difficulty: 2.5627062218671076e+21,
        head: "0x51f16c3910cc604cc319978b619ed0d4147df67f77b4bbd16478d73e5103305e",
        version: 63
      }
    }
}, {
    caps: ["eth/63"],
    id: "a7f1a8a46cc2f6c7bbecc8d7d35647fe5480dbd82c04583ff35ef1cfcb045965e1d5dce5c112f6fdcb0d63e90a4bb7392daaf8adfa784ef0a77e320a7060f0aa",
    name: "Geth/v1.7.3-unstable-86f6568f/linux-amd64/go1.9",
    network: {
      inbound: false,
      localAddress: "172.31.22.171:60034",
      remoteAddress: "91.224.140.211:19300",
      static: false,
      trusted: false
    },
    protocols: {
      eth: {
        difficulty: 2.425191243091731e+21,
        head: "0xce35300c184f9e1b3d8d7a7b7d8c0839782b99d6e61a8fffab83304ede90c726",
        version: 63
      }
    }

}]
```

Console command to start geth

```
geth --mine --minerthreads=4
```

Comment: What is the geth launch command line used? Does the node have enough peers? Run `admin.peers` from the geth console.

Comment: It does have peers. 8 of them.

Comment: What does `eth.blockNumber` return? It appears you are syncing against mainnet it is very unlikely you will be able to mine there using geth. Also try `eth.getBlock(5099300)` to obtain a recent block.

Comment: eth.blockNumber also returns 0.
eth.getBlock(5099300) does return me the block details.

Comment: The block number is correctly updated now. It just took a long while from the point syncing was false to eth.blockNumber reflecting the correct block. Is this expected?

Answer (score 1):

Syncing is false because you did not sync with any of the available network chain.

And latest block is 0 since you did not mine any block on your own.

Do any of the above to get a valid block

Answer (score 0):

Same issue with 
Geth/v1.8.2-stable-b8b9f7f4/linux-amd64/go1.9.4
It took more than 12 hour in initial sync.

To fix it I did : 
a. created a address 
(e.g. personal.newAccount("some-strong-password"))
b. Transferred 0.1 ETH to newly created address.
After that 
eth.getBlock("latest").number started returning correct value.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/14338:

Geth uses fast sync by default. The block states are unavailable for intermediate blocks and are downloaded only for the recent state. As such, up to the point that sync completes, the latest complete block is zero, since all newer blocks are incomplete during sync. When fast sync finishes, it downloads the associated state for the head, so the head block becomes complete and the latest block can be bumped to the current head.

Answer (score -2):

the `eth.getBlock("latest").number` returning 0 means no block was mined. maybe you just didn't deploy anything or make any transaction. you should check your nodejs server, i think.