# eth.getBalance() return 0 though fully synced

Tags: go-ethereum, truffle, fast-sync

So I stopped `geth`, deleted all files from `~/Library/Ethereum/geth/chaindata`, and restarted geth with `--fast --rpc` and waited for like 24h, and have like 53GB of `ldb` files now. I used to run `eth.syncing` every once in a while to see the progress and it always gave me something like this:

```
> eth.syncing
{
  currentBlock: 5097903,
  highestBlock: 5132166,
  knownStates: 4631303,
  pulledStates: 4624883,
  startingBlock: 4410604
}
```

Until it started returning `false` which made me conclude that the sync is done:

```
> eth.syncing
false
```

YET! `eth.getBalanace('0xa76ada7b7450b260f7d585556a53168352be8fba')` returns 0!

Here is my account on etherscan: https://etherscan.io/address/0xa76ada7b7450b260f7d585556a53168352be8fba

What's more weird is that `eth.getTransaction` for txs from the last few days returns `null`. Here's an example of a tx from 4 days ago:

```
> eth.getTransaction('0xaa4199162f87d2ded2f0a650f8283955dea278a19d964a262c08121bce74a3fd')
null
```

It can only get transactions from like 7 days ago.

When will it ever fully sync? Am I doing anything wrong? My all purpose here (this is why I run with `--rpc`) is to be able to migrate from `truffle`. Still can't do that because it claims I don't have sufficient funds! Well, eth.getBalance() returns 0 so from its perspective it must be right, though you can see on etherscan the figure is 0.049, not 0!

Comment: What does `eth.blockNumber` returns? From some reports here https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/40041/fast-syncing-has-completed-yet-eth-blocknumber-still-returns-0, https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/39784/sync-done-but-latest-block-number-0, https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/40070/geth-v1-8-unable-to-download-the-last-65-blocks-for-the-mainnet it appears with geth v1.8 it takes some time to finish.

Comment: it returns 0... btw, now after 10 hours it seems to be syncing again... eth.syncing shows a json. I really don't know if I'm figuring out this process right anymore. to my best understanding, once the sync is done, there should be no more sync, only incremental catchup with the chain that is not refered to as "sync"

Comment: at least now it returns data for the 4 old days transaction

Comment: What is your command line to start geth? From this answer about how fast sync works https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/40193 it doesn't sync to head immediately but slightly behind to avoid chain reorgs, when that is done it will advance further. If for some reason, slow disk io or bad network bandwidth, it is possible that it will need several iterations. Until `eth.blockNumber` is a recent blocks I'd say it didn't finish syncing.

Comment: even if it is, it's not that it is answered there. It is very frustrating as i never get to a state where my chain is synced and I can't deploy any contracts.

Comment: Are you using a HDD or a SSD? How much memory your computer have? Are you doing something else meanwhile? Synchronizing can be pretty taxing on a computer. A SSD is more than recommended, geth v1.8 has some enhancements for HDD but I didn't try yet (before that it was almost impossible to use HDD). Have enough RAM at least 8Gb, set a cache of 1024 to speed things. I usually left it overnight and a full  sync in fast mode will complete, other modes can take longer. It uses a lots of IO if you are using the same computer for other task it will take more time.

Comment: I'm using HDD. Well, I switched to use `infura`, I see no point in having a synced node for deploy purposes when I can use infura instead.